# Android PHONE_STATE not fired if phone is inactive for a night

Tags: android, android-intent

My Android app invokes a webservice or sends SMS when a new incoming call received. I use `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` intent for this.

Everything works fine, except: the app must be restarted every morning.

It looks like if something prevents the app from receiving this broadcast if it is not used for hours, for a night.

What can cause this kind of behavior?

```
<application>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

Comment: How do you know that `onReceive()` is not being called?

Comment: I use the same code in three different apps. 1: sends SMS, 2: invokes web service, 3: writes a local SQLite DB. I'm facing the same issue in all of the apps.

Comment: I'm not sure if you misunderstood my question, but that does not answer it.

Comment: I think that onReceive() is not called, because the code that is invoked is very-very simple and works all day long, and some users reported the same issue in different applications. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this behavior, because on my test devices it works well. So I think maybe some "useless but important" virus checker or "3rd party system optimizer" application cause this.

Comment: OK, it sounds to me like you are not using a foreground service. This means that Android will very often stop your app, simply because it is not currently onscreen, and the resources are needed for other things. Did you account for this in the design? That is, do you test the app by doing a PHONE_STATE change when the app is in a terminated state?